# p5.js Getting the ball to move out from the middle and split into different directions

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a simple click the ball game called popThatBall, I have used classes to create the ball and push it multiple times to an array using a for loop.

I am wanting to make it so the ball bounces out from the middle in different directions, rather than following the same directions. I have tried to write a solution to my problem using random and iterating through an array of positive and negative numbers (which is what I was told I should try), but it all follows the same direction and goes to the bottom right hand corner, which is what I don't understand.

Here is a gif of what is currently happening:

[image: Ball Moving and not working]

Here is the move() function currently being called when the ball is being created:

Also here is the posRange and negRange array used to cycle through random numbers

```
let posRange = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
let negRange = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

```
move() {
        // checking if the ball is still in its start postion
        if (this.center) {
            // push the ball out with the directon (speed) that matches the range 
            this.speedX = random(posRange)
            // again with Y direction
            this.speedY = random(negRange)
            // move ball across X axis
            this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
            // move ball across Y axis
            this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
            // the ball is no longer in the center
            // reset speed variables to orginal values.
            this.speedX = this.speeds[0]
            this.speedY = this.speeds[1]
            this.center = false;

        }else if(!this.center){
            this.x = this.x + this.speedX;
            this.y = this.y + this.speedY;
        }
```

This may not be relevant but will include the gm_createBalls which is called during the draw function.

```
    function gm_activateBalls(){
        for (let i = 0; i < Balls.length; i++) {
            Balls[i].show()
            Balls[i].move()
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `random()` function to initialize the speed values only returns positive values. You could, for example, use `this.speedX = random(-1, 1)` to choose any random value between -1 and 1 and thus also allow for "negative" speeds (i.e., some of your balls initially going to the left).

Answer (score 0):

Use a function similar to this:

```js
this.speedX *= random(-1,1)
```